# Return array of pointers by reference

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

Inside one of my classes i've got a

```
Reservation * availability[30] = {nullptr};
```

(which I of course initialize later with some values).

Nevertheless, I've got a getReservations() function which is supposed to return a reference to that array of 30 elements, so that it can be used like:

```
getReservations()[i] ...
```

How should I declare that function?

Comment: Side note: I'd personally initialize the array with `= {};`. It looks like you think all of the elements are initialized to the `nullptr` you've written, but they're actually value-initialized.

Comment: @Quentin well, value-initialization and nullptr initialization do the same thing, don't they? I agree though, it's silly to treat the first element differently.

Comment: @user2079303 yes, that's my point. There's no functional difference but it is a bit misleading.

Comment: @Quentin my point is that is it really *misleading* when it leads to the same result with no difference? It's just silly in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax for declaring a function that returns the array by reference is this:

```
Reservation * (& getReservations())[30];
```

Of course, as you can see, you shouldn't use this in real life. Instead do it with a type alias:

```
using Reservations = Reservation * [30];

Reservations & getReservations();
```

Or, because arrays aren't bounds-checked anyway, just return a pointer which you can then index like an array:

```
Reservation * getReservations();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Reservation *(&getReservations())[30];
```

should do it for you.

Please remember of dangling references and pointer management.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use modern C++:

```
using ReservationArray = std::array<Reservation*, 30>;

ReservationArray _availability;
```

and to return that as:

```
ReservationArray& getReservations()
```

Comment: raw pointers are still _incredibly_ useful in modern C++.  Don't mistake "pointers" for "owning dynamic values". Those are orthogonal concepts.

Comment: true, they are useful in some specific cases. But why would you recommend using raw pointers here?

Comment: You made the (unsubstantiated) assumption that these pointers own data. If they're non-owning, then `unique_ptr` causes double delete undefined behavior, which is very very bad. These pointers could just as likely be nullable references, in which case `Reservation*` is the correct thing to use.